# Form Control Button to Export Worksheet to CSV While Excluding First Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, export

I have a workbook that has 4 worksheets. The first worksheet gets populated and then the other 3 worksheets are populated from the data in the first through formulas. I have to export the 3 worksheets to a csv in order to upload them to a website for data import.

I created a form control button, that I placed on each worksheet, that will export my worksheet to a csv. Instead of creating a floating button, I put the button in the first row and froze the first row so that the button would remain on top.

When exporting the csv it will export the first row as a blank row which causes an error when I upload to the website so I was wondering if there is a way to have this form control button macro exclude the first row when exporting to csv.

Here is the VBA code for my 3 buttons:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ELINSaveAsCSV()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ELIN")
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\RedSky\ELIN.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub

Public Sub ERLSaveAsCSV()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ERL")
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\RedSky\ERL.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
Sub UsersSaveAsCSV()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Users")
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\RedSky\Users.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I would also like it to delete columns C, D, & E prior to exporting on one of my sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following before saving the file as csv. This code should select the entire first row and delete it from the worksheet.

```
wbkExport.Worksheets.Item(1).Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Would that command be similar if I wish to delete columns C, D, & E as well?

Comment: @AaylanZ To delete a column use `.EntireColumn`. To delete columns C, D & E: `.Range("C1:E1".EntireColumn.Delete`

Comment: So would the line after the row delete look like this? wbkExport.Worksheets.Item(1).Range("C1:E1").EntireColumn.Delete

Comment: I got it to work perfectly! You have no idea how much time you saved me. There is no information on the web about this specific issue so much appreciated!

Comment: After closing the 1st sheet, continue by setting the next worksheet